# I'm trying to dynamically create an array within a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, delete-operator

So this is my function.

```
void Array::addValueStruct(int id, int size, int type, int compareValue, StoredData temp[])
{
    //struct
    StoredData* tempStruct = new StoredData [arrSize+1];
    for (int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        tempStruct[i] = temp[i];
    }

    arrSize = arrSize + 1;

    delete [] temp;

    temp = tempStruct;

    temp[arrSize-1]={id,size,type,compareValue};
}
```

Here's where I initialise my struct

```
StoredData testData[5]={{0,50,5,1},{1,25,5,2},{2,40,2,3},{3,10,5,4},{4,80,3,5}};
```

Now, I'm about 20% sure that the reason why it isn't working is because I need to use the NEW function to create the data, but I've trying searching the web and I can't find anything to help me.

What I want to happen, is I want to pass the struct array through the function to increase its size by 1.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How do you test the `addValueStruct`?

Comment: I want to be able to pass the struct through the function, and I want the function to increase the size of the struct array by 1.

Comment: "it isn't working" <--- world's worst problem specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here. One of them is as you suspect, you cannot `delete` something that was statically defined. That problem can be got past by having a static definition and an initialization function that performs the dynamic allocation and copies the static data in.

Another issue is that you're using call-by-value on the `temp` variable. This might be less than obvious since, as you know, you're able to modify the data `temp` points to -- the problem is that you also want to perform `temp = tempStruct;` where, presumably, you want to affect the caller's view of the value passed in... if you want to affect what the caller sees, you need to call-by-reference.

Comment: How exactly do I statically define a struct array? I was able to do it with a standard array within any issues, but it doesn't seem to work the same way for structs.

Comment: You're already defining a static array of structs -- it's how you're initializing `testData` currently. I would suggest renaming your current `testData` to `initialTestData`, creating `StoredData *testData=NULL;`, and writing a function that copies the contents of `initialTestData` into `testData` (which will be properly allocated using `new`).

Comment: So the function should simple copy the contents from one variable to the other? Where does the allocation of new come into it? I'm fairly new to using new and delete.

Comment: The function should first set testData to the return of new (google "c++ allocate array" and you'll find a good example but something like `testData = new StoredData[5];`, then copy each of the 5 elements into it. This is only a little different from what you're currently doing when you add an element to `tempStruct` now.

Comment: Scratch that, all fixed now. About that other issue you mentioned though, what exactly is the problem? After testing my code I've noticed that for some reason my function resets all of the values within my struct to '-17891602'.

Comment: The other problem is that due to pass-by-value, your change to `temp` is not seen by the caller... it's only a local (to the function) change. You've deleted the memory it points to though, which could be the cause of the values being reset. Try changing the function slightly to `void Array::addValueStruct(int id, int size, int type, int compareValue, StoredData &temp[])` (I'm not sure if that's the exact correct syntax, but notice the `&` next to `temp` for call-by-reference).